# Wamp server can't start (orange icon)

Tags: apache, wamp

I can't start wamp server on win7. I'm using vhosts, everything was fine untill I restart wamp server.

httpd-vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin *.*@*.com
DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Rossko\Documents\PHP\wamp\www\***.local"
ServerName ***.local
ErrorLog "C:\Users\Rossko\Documents\PHP\wamp\apache\apache2.4.9\logs\***.local-error.log"
CustomLog "C:\Users\Rossko\Documents\PHP\wamp\apache\apache2.4.9\logs\***.local-access.log" common
```

in Apache error log is nothing and port 80 is empty. Why is still orange and failed to start? Any idea? I have more virtual hosts in httpd-vhost.conf than projects in www/ folder (not enough time for copy) Is it possible that the error is coused by this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if Apache fails to start, look at the Windows Event Log under

```
Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application
```

And then look for Errors report from a `Source` of `Apache`

If Apache fails before it can open its error log, errors are written to the Event log.

Second a good way to test your http.conf file and any files that are included within httpd.conf is to do this :-

Launch a command window (Dos Box)

```
C:
CD \Users\Rossko\Documents\PHP\wamp\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
httpd -t
```

This should validate the httpd.conf file and all included files, if there are errors they will be reported with a filename and a line number.

Fix the error and then try the `httpd -t` command again until it responds with an `OK` message.

If you have defined more Virtual Hosts than you have actually created `DocumetRoot` folders for, it should just report a `cannot find file` type message in the Apache error log on startup. It should not actually stop Apache from starting.

Comment: thank you very much, the error was in httpd-vhost.conf file. I had ErrorLog and CustomLog with bad path